# Is there a chance to user Salesforce Authenticator App in a Login-Flow?

Tags: authentication

I want to use the Salesforce authenticator app for a 2FA-Login in Salesforce. But I only want to use it if the User isn't in the trusted IP ranges which you can set in Setup under Network Access. Someone have a workaround for that?

Comment: [Custom Login Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm) is the overall solution to this. It will work with Authenticator via TOTP (enter a code..) but you won't be able to do a push notification + a tap.

Comment: Okay.. thats what I found aswell. Sad to hear that there is no workaround for the full functionally Salesforce Authenticator App.

Comment: Your best option out of the box is to use Authenticator for everyone and [auto-approve based on location + IP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317978&type=1&mode=1).